# Can jquery animate the background picture position where it is loading?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

If I have one background picture `bg.png` width 900px, height:3000px, I want to get this effection, when open the page, loading and show the background image from top to bottom.  the scroll-y will animate the the position where the picture background is loading and show.(after loading all the page, the position should be the bottom of the page. 
Can this effection make through jquery? And how? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/backgroundPosition-Effect